# JQuery: how to replace hard-coded url for the hosted page?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this:

```
$("input.fetchData").click(function () {
 path = "/data";
 var dataurl = 'http://localhost:8000' + path;
```

...

It works locally but when I deploy to my server it stops working.  I want to replace localhost with the host that served the page. How?

Comment: Btw, I think JQuery ajax ,if you using it, does not need the full path. You should be fine with "dataurl = path".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location) to get the information, but do you really need a full path? For ajax requests and such, a relative path should be sufficient. For instance:

```
$("input.fetchData").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/data",
        ...
    });
});
```

```
Fetches                       If page served from
-------                       ----------------------
http://localhost:8000/data    http://localhost:8000
http://w3.example.com/data    http://w3.example.com
```

...etc. If you want to fetch from a peer of the current location, you may find you want `../data` rather than `/data`, which will always start at the root of the server.

Regardless, if you need a full path, here's a précis of `location` properties:

- `protocol` - E.g., `http` or `https`
- `hostname` - The hostname
- `port` - The port (80 is the default, but of course it could be 8000 as in your question)
- `host` - `hostname` and `port` pre-combined for you

...and then you may or may not want `pathname`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "[window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location)" to know your host

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the `window.location` object, it has properties such as `window.location.host` which you could use to construct the URL, such as:

```
$("input.fetchData").click(function () {
  path = "/data";
  var dataurl = 'http://' + window.location.host + path;
  // ...
});
```

Comment: must put window.location.port, and if that is 80 can to obviate

Comment: `window.location.host + ':8000'` will duplicate the port if the page was served on any port but `80` (`host` includes `port`, you may want `hostname`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use relative rather than absolute URLs, or you can go through the window.location members in the DOM.

Relative URLs should work in most cases, but if they don't you can always re-create your URL with something like:

var curUrl = document.location.protocol + "//" + document.location.host + document.location.pathname;